# CSS Float Wont Work

Tags: html, css

I just started learning CSS, grids,  and I'm having a problem .

Tthe code -

HTML -

```
<body>
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <h1>Grid</h1>
        <div class"grid">
            <div class="col col-2-3"> Test </div>
            <div class="col col-1-3"> Test </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And CSS

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}

.page-wrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: grey;
}

.grid {
    overflow: hidden;

    .col {
        float: left:
    }
}

.col-2-3 {
    width: 66.66%;
    background: red;
}

.col-1-3 {
    width: 33.33%;
    background: blue;
}
}
```

How come **float: left;** is not being applied?
[Pause the video](http://youtu.be/9ScOYtky7CM?t=7m54s), this is how it should look, but it doesn't for me.
It worked if I deleted the .col { float: left } part and applied float: left; to both .col-1-3 and .col-2-3. Other than that, I can;t find what I did wrong.
I googled the clearfix "hack" but I didn't know how to apply it.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: In that video, Chris is using a CSS preprocessor called SCSS that has a slightly different syntax than CSS. You'll want to remove extra brackets in your stylesheet.

Comment: Tone back the percentages.  I have never added the total up to 100% width and had it work for me.  Change to `width: 33.32%`

Comment: Fix the following typo also: <div class="grid"> (missing = sign)

Comment: @imjared I think he brackets are off, not too many.  If you look at .grid, there isn't a closing one.  He wraps it, it maybe a syntax of SCSS, haven't used that one, so I maybe wrong.

Comment: @justin you can see in the video that SCSS is being used. In this case, it's correct syntax for scss but it definitely won't work in vanilla CSS

Comment: There is a typo in your **.col** class. You put a colon on the property float: left: instead of a semicolon **float: left;** [CSS float](https://kolosek.com/css-float/) property article gives a more detailed explanation that will help you with any further questions about the property.

Answer (score 4):

Basic float problem is this: `float: left;` instead of `float: left:`

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in the `.col` definition - `float: left:` should be `float: left;` (colon where a semicolon should be).

Answer (score 1):

Fix your `float: left:` to `float: left;`.  As others have mentioned, fix your brakets.

Answer (score 0):

First thing fix your css :

```
body {
    background-color: white;

}

 .page-wrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: grey;
}

.grid {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.col {
    float: left; /* should be ; and not : */
}

.col-2-3 {
    width: 66.66%;
    background: red;

}

.col-1-3 {
    width: 33.33%;
    background: blue;
}
```

This is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Tfd5k/) that works fine.

Comment: Hmh, but the guy in the video was writing like that, weird. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your CSS.

1. You are nesting a property inside another property.

   ```
   .grid {
       overflow: hidden;
       .col {
           float: left:
       }
   }
   ```

   You need to change this so that `.col` is outside of `.grid`.

   ```
   .grid {
       overflow: hidden;
   }
   .col {
       float: left:
   }
   ```
2. You mistyped the closing semicolon on an attribute inside `.col`.

   ```
   float: left:
   ```

   Should be...

   ```
   float: left;
   ```